# Sharepoint `Unsupported segment type` when checkin/chekout file

Tags: rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'd like to use the **checkout/checkin feature on the OneDrive REST API**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_checkout

I'm facing two issues:

**1st issue** - the file info API returns `publication` property as `published`, even the file is manually checked out

Request:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SITE_ID/drive/items/FILE_ID?select=name,id,publication`

Response:

```
{
    "id": "01KJOOXJHF77OPSR7HWVCKSTHBQJQZEBJI",
    "name": "diamond.mmap",
    "publication": {
        "level": "published",
        "versionId": "2.0"
    }
}
```

[image]

**2nd Issue** - weird response of the checkout/checkin endpoint:

I'm using the endpoint as defined here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_checkout

e.g.
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SITE_ID/drive/items/FILE_ID/checkout`

Responds with:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: sites/fe688d8ed4a2/drive/items/01KJOQZEBJI/checkout",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a7d18555-3e74-4aea-ad92-539481f6c33b",
            "date": "2018-02-21T09:17:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Any thought what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [`/checkin`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_checkin) and [`/checkout`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_checkout) endpoints are  currently in `beta`.

Try changing your URI's root from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/checkout
```

Comment: beta throws `"code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",      "message": "Unknown Error",` :(

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/DRIVE_ID/items/ITEM_ID` gets the file info correctly

Comment: I'm able to checkout a file using the Sharepoint API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest), over the standard authentication (I took a cookie from browser to authenticate the checkout request). However, I need to use the OAuth. Which endpoints for auth is compatible with Sharepoint API?

Comment: access token acquired from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` is not working

Comment: @marc-lafleur the `/checkin` `/checkout` endpoints are mentioned in the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_checkout without any mention of "Beta". Also, we tried both the `beta` and `v1.0` endpoints without success. Do you know whether this is a known issue at Microsoft?

Comment: The OneDrive docs currently don't separate beta vs production features. There is an open pull request to fix this. Please add how you are obtaining your token and a sample token to your question. It sounds like you've got the wrong scopes.

Comment: @marc-lafleur for now at least the beta API is working, is there any estimation when this will be available on the official API? The scopes we are using are `files.readwrite User.Read offline_access sites.readwrite.all`